# Wi-Fi unstable on Macbook Pro 2018, Sonoma)

Tags: mac, wifi

My Macbook Pro 2018 13" running macOS 14.2.1 is systematically having problems starting a Wi-Fi connection and to keeping it connected. This is happening with different Wi-Fi networks at different places. It drops Wi-Fi network in either a couple of minutes or less than one hour.

My iPhone is not having issues connecting to Wi-Fi and I can indirectly access Wi-Fi with my mac when I connect my iPhone  with a cable.

I've restarted my mac several times, and to verify the Wi-Fi configuration in settings. There, all the configurations are in automatic and all the proxies options are switched off. I also tried the automatic diagnostic, but I did not find anything relevant. I tried swithing off the private relay.

I think this issue started a couple of weeks ago.

Any suggestions? More data?

Comment: you probably changed the battery on that one, and in doing so, you probably damaged the wifi card

Comment: See whether you can reproduce the problem in Recovery mode. If you can, it's caused by a hardware fault. Likely a broken or disconnected antenna cable.

Comment: Thanks. I tested in Recovery mode, and the problem persists. I have changed my battery, but only in 2020 (it was defective, apple changed it for free). The issue I am experienciing now probably started about 4 months ago, and it became much worse recently, about a month. So it seems I will have to repair the wifi card...